# Changing wordpress language

Tags: php, wordpress, mo

I'm trying to change the wordpress default language from english to swedish. I uploaded the language directory to wp-content with the swedish .mo file.

Ive defined language in the config.php file but it won't update, when I'm logged in and under updates I can see an option that says restore core files with swedish so I know its working only when I update it is still is english.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need also .po files.

Comment: Belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following links, they deal exactly with the situation you describe (and propose  same kind of easy workaround):

http://devblog.fishol.pl/php/wordpress/how-to-restore-default-wordpress-language/

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-language-to-english-after-dutch-installation

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
In order to change the language in wordpress blog you need to perform these steps:

1) Login into WordPress Blog Administrator Control Panel.
2) Click on Settings.
3) Click on General Settings.
4) Select the desired Language from the drop down menu at Language section.
5) Click on save changes.
```

[read more](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-language-5)

Comment: I don't that option, no drop downmenu or anything about language in my general settings

Comment: Here is drop down option Timezone, read it for more information http://en.support.wordpress.com/language-settings/

Comment: Same situation here. Can't see the language drop downs. It might be useful to note that I've installed WordPress with my language installed as default, in contrast to downloading and adding it later. For a workaround to this situation (which seems quite common) check the solution I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To change language use

```
add_filter('locale', 'setLocale22323');

function setLocale22323($locale) {
  if ( is_admin() ) {
    return 'en_US';
  }
  return $locale; 
}
```